# Reduce outer space for Entry in Android

Tags: maui

I use a Grid with 3 different Rows in a .NET MAUI App. The RowHeight is already set.

When looking at the RowHeight, I can't reduce the size as is getting already too small then (as can be seen at the selection color on the top).

But, what I can see is that the space below the line of an Entry and at the top (I would say outer) could be reduced.

On iOS it does not bother that much, but in Android currently yes.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suppleme to Mert Altiparmak's answer.

You can use the Margin property to **reduce** the outer space by setting it as a  negative. Such as `Margin="-2"`. If the value is positive number, it will increase the outer space.

In addition, the Margin can be passed four parameters such as `Margin = "left, top, right, bottom"`. You can set one of then as a negative to reduce one side space.

And you said

> On iOS it does not bother that much, but in Android currently yes.

So you can use [Platform differences in the xaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/essential-syntax#platform-differences) such as:

```
    <Entry.Margin>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Default="0">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="-2,-2,-2,-2" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Entry.Margin>
```

==== Additional ====

Maybe also possible with this a Style like this?

```
<Style TargetType="Entry">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{OnPlatform 0, iOS='0, 0, 0, 0', Android='0, -2, 0, -2'}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. I also added it in combination with a Style that can be used just for a Grid as in my case. If not valuable, please delete...

Comment: Using style is a good way to set all the entry in the project. Good job! @OXO

Comment: Probably could also leave out the 0 in ```{OnPlatform ...}``` or change to a Margin value like  '0, -5, 0, -5' to cover all the other supported platforms other than the specified (iOS and Android)

Comment: The default value is `0 ,0 ,0 ,0`, so you can remove `iOS='0, 0, 0, 0'`. @OXO

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I wasn't sure if nothing is set then when iOS is left out. But it makes sense as you said

Answer (score 1):

You should change margin settings. You can set it around 1-5 and it will be thinner.

```
Margin="2"
```